# Closed Surfaces are combinatorial surfaces

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to verify the following claims about closed surfaces from the book Basic Topology by M.A. Armstrong.

> If h: |K|$\to$ S is a triangulation of a closed surface we are going to show that the simplicial complex K must be a combinatorial surface. Show that:
>
> i) K cannot have dimension 1.
>
> ii) K does not contain a simplex with dimension greater than 2.
>
> iii) every edge in K lies in exactly two triangles.
>
> iv) each vertex lies in at least three triangles whose union forms a cone with apex v.

I started with i). Suppose that the claim is false.  Then there is a complex K such that dim(K)=1. This implies that no simplex in K may have dimension greater than 1. This means that all simplexes in K are either single vertices or straight line-segments between two vertices. Moreover we can guarantee the existence of at least one simplex with dimension one.

Since S is a closed surface it is compact, connected and hausdorff.

I also know that each two vertices of K can be joined by an edge path. That is, they can be joined by a sequence of 1-simplexes in K.

In order to produce a contradiction I have to find a 2-simplex contained in K.

So take a 1-simplex $\sigma$ in K with vertices v,w. For any vertex z in K  there are edge paths joining v and w to z. I now have to prove that for  some z that is neither v nor w that these edge paths consist only of a single edge.

The problem is that there seems to be no way to show that.

Comment: What is your definition of a surface and how much topology do you know? For instance, do you know the invariance of domain theorem?

Comment: Armstrong defines a surface as a Hausdorff space in which each point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to the plane. Unforntunately I do not know the invariance of domain theorem.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $(0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to an open subset of $R^2$?

Comment: No, I would have to think about that.

Comment: You cannot solve this problem without being able to do the exercise about an open interval and an open subset of the plane.